# PHP and AJAX database connection

Tags: php, ajax

My problem is that whenever I run the index.html file the result of ajax is too fast and the page reloads .Thus, finally no output shows in DIV element.

Html Page (index.html)

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <script src="ajax.js"></script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>

 <FORM onSubmit='sendEmpID(this.roll)' action='index.html'> 
 <input id='roll' type='text'>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </FORM>
 <P>
 <DIV id="emp"><B>Employee info will be listed here.</B></DIV>
 </P>
 </BODY>

 </HTML>
```

Thus follows the ajax code:

```
var xmlHttp;
function sendEmpID(str)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
        return;
    }
    var url="getemployee.php";
    url=url+"?q="+str;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged; 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); }
function stateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        document.getElementById("emp").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText; 
    } 
}
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    return xmlHttp;

}
```

And this is PHP part(getemployee.php)

```
<html>
<head>

<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Not able to connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("emp", $con);
$query="SELECT * FROM ajax_example WHERE ID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>WPM</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sex'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['wpm'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</head>
</html>
```

Database content:

```
ID  name    age sex     wpm
1   Frank   45  male    87
2   Jerry   23  male    20
3   Jill    22  female  72
4   Julie   35  female  90
5   Regis   75  male    44
6   Tracy   27  female  0
```

So whenever I run the index.html and  insert 1 in input and press submit.
No result get displayed. After few tries I noticed the table appearing but disappers too quickly.
Please tell shall i have timer set in ajax code or there is any problem in my code.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to do a `return false;` on your form submit. Right now it is doing your ajax, but then also posting the form / reloading the page. You need to prevent the form from doing its normal action.

Comment: Don't pass user input direct to your query. This is how SQL injections occur. Use prepared statements and update driver to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.